# How can I use the Google gapi.client.load function to work with Google's Sentiment Analysis?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use the Google 'gapi.client.load' function with Google's Natural Language sentiment analysis framework, but I'm stuck. Specifically I can't figure out how to do something like this

```
return gapi.client.language.documents.analyzeSentiment.list({
        'type':'PLAIN_TEXT', 'content' = 'I am so happy'
      });
```

Because I don't know what's supposed to come after gapi.client. The documentation from google says

> Loads the client library interface to a particular API with discovery document URL or JSON object. Returns a Promise-like goog.Thenable object that resolves when the API interface is loaded. The loaded API interface will be in the form gapi.client.api.collection.method. For example, the Moderator API would create methods like gapi.client.moderator.series.list.

But because I'm a moron, I can't figure out what the API name for the Sentiment Analysis tool would be. I assume it would be 'language'.  Next I can't figure out what the collection would be. Although I'm pretty sure the method should be analyzeSentiment. But I'm not sure, because I don't know Javascript very well, so the documentation isn't particularly helpful to me. And the fact that the documentation for different parts of the Google Cloud API are written differently makes it different to find the parallel structure I'd need to interpret them.

Can you help me out?

Thanks,
Brad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that I didn't have the variables for the function filled in correctly.  I had

```
return gapi.client.language.documents.analyzeSentiment.list({
    'type':'PLAIN_TEXT', 'content' = 'I am so happy'
  });
```

What I should have had was this

```
return gapi.client.language.documents.analyzeSentiment({
        'document': {
                  'type': 'PLAIN_TEXT',
                  'content': 'I am so happy'
               }
```

Specifically, I should have had a nested json, with the outer json having an element called 'document', and that document having a two element json with the elements of 'type', and 'content'.

Then it works.